# Any way to edit an {% extends %} based on the date?

Tags: django, django-templates

At my work, we only have access to the front-end/templating part of the server.  I'm definitely not a Django programmer, but I understand the templates pretty well.  What we're looking to do is, given a date or a date range, load a different {% extends %} based on the date.  All I could find was examples on how to do it on the back-end.  Some ideas I've tried that haven't worked:

```
{% extends "base"+{% now "Ymd"  %} %}
```

Even if that did work, on regular days, I want to to default to

```
{% extends "base" %}
```

anyway, which that method wouldn't do.  So I was thinking something like

```
{% ifequal {% now "Ymd"  %} "20140120" %}
  {% extends "base2014120" %}
{% else %}
  {% extends "base" %}
{% endifequal %}
```

But that obviously didn't work either.  We're hoping to come up with some solution so I don't have to keep logging in at midnight to manually make the change.

Comment: I dont see anyway to do this without access to the backend and render "now" into the template or handle this with a custom tag/filter.

Comment: Ok, you'd probably know more than me.  Any thoughts on thinking outside of the box?  Make a chron job to rename the base templates, for example?  I think it would work, but I really don't like it.

Comment: To help our outside-of-the-box thinking, could you provide us with the context-variables that *are* available to you? It's a long-shot, but perhaps one of them conceals a hidden gem... **Edit:** I wonder if the date is available on the request somewhere...?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** This is truly filthy, and potentially a security concern, but if you're *absolutely sure* that you can't get the date added to the context, then I have found a way.

Set a cookie containing the date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie="datecookie={% now 'Ymd' %}";
</script>
```

You can then use this value in the template thus:

```
{% extends 'base'|add:request.COOKIES.datecookie|add:'.html'|default:'base.html' %}
```

If you cannot set the cookie before the page is loaded, then you could make the default template set the cookie and redirect to `.`. This would create a new request, and the cookie would be set. (Although I wouldn't want to visit your site with cookies turned off ;)

There you have it: the nastiest hack I have ever written.

**Update:** I suspect that upon seeing that you are being reduced to this, your back-end developers may take pity on you and just add the date to the context.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll definitely keep this option in mind.  And we don't have any back-end developers any more as the company who set up the system for us went out of business.

Comment: In that case, I hesitantly suggest you look into learning some back-end. You might be surprised at how accessible django is. It has a great community, fantastic documentation and supporting literature, and of course stack overflow is a great resource. The [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) is a good place to start. Once you complete step 3 of the tutorial, you should have an idea of how to add something to the context. If not, you could always add another question here `;)`

Comment: I actually know quite a bit of backend… though all Perl and PHP and no Python, and our set-up is some super-custom CMS built on top of Django, and it's frustrated us enough that we've already decided to move away from it and to something that would better suit my experience without my having to learn another language/framework.  Right now we're just looking for band-aid fixes for the current site to last until we create something new.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as patronising, that wasn't my intent. I just feel that it would probably be easier/safer to make that modification than it would to use the nasty code I have produced above `:)`

Comment: Definitely not… you were great.  Thank you for your guidance.